# Why does the IntoIterator trait require explicitly specifying the associated type Item?

Tags: rust, iterator, traits

Since the associated type `IntoIter` of the `IntoIterator` trait, implements the `Iterator` trait, isn't that sufficient to infer the associated type `Item`?

Comment: @L.F. OP is asking why `IntoIterator` has a `type Item` when that information _could_ be obtained from `type IntoIter`

Comment: @vallentin Sorry, I didn't realize it's referring to the `IntoIter` associated type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does the `IntoIterator` trait require explicit `type Item` declaration?

It *doesn't*. You are correct that when you `impl IntoIterator for ...` then `Item` is *redundant*, and *could* be obtained through `IntoIter`.

---

This was introduced in [PR #22313](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/22313). In short, the reason is was introduced was to simplify where clauses. If you have to specify `IntoIter` then that can quickly become cumbersome.

```rust
where I: IntoIterator<IntoIter = ...>
```

In that case it is much easier to do:

```rust
where I: IntoIterator<Item = ...>
```

---

Let's consider a random example, like `print_strings`. Then before you needed to do something like this:

```rust
fn print_strings<I, T>(iter: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator<IntoIter = T>,
    T: Iterator<Item = &'static str>,
{
    for s in iter {
        println!("{}", s);
    }
}
```

Whereas now that can be simplified to just:

```rust
fn print_strings<I>(iter: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = &'static str>,
{
    for s in iter {
        println!("{}", s);
    }
}

fn main() {
    print_strings(vec!["foo", "bar", "baz"]);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think the first part of your answer is correct, since you *do* need the `type Item` declaration when implementing the `IntoIterator` trait, it's not optional despite being redundant because it's the same as `<Self::IntoIter as Iterator>::Item`. (At least not until associated type defaults are stabilized.) You don't need it in trait bounds, sure, but that's true of any associated type, redundant or not.

Comment: I meant "redundant" as in `type Item` wasn't needed to implement `IntoIterator` prior, it is now of course. What I meant was that it wasn't introduced due to an issue with `IntoIterator` itself. But instead introduced to simplify where clauses. :)